# Error response and ODataError serialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a Web API 2 OData service where if there's a problem I'm returning a HttpResponseException containing an ODataError e.g.

```
    public ActionResult Post(Customer entity)
    {
        try
        {
            Repository.Save(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ODataException(500, ex);
        }
    }

    protected virtual Exception ODataException(HttpStatusCode code, string message = null, Exception ex = null, IList<ODataErrorDetail> details = null)
    {
        return ODataException(code, code.ToODataError(message, ex, details, !Request.ShouldIncludeErrorDetail()));
    }

    protected virtual Exception ODataException(HttpStatusCode code, ODataError error)
    {
        var message = Request.CreateErrorResponse(code, error);

        return new HttpResponseException(message);
    }
```

As noted elsewhere, [Error Handling for ASP.NET OData Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389070/error-handling-for-asp-net-odata-web-api), since OData V3 there is a standard serialized response looking like this...

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "A custom error code",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-us",
            "value": "A custom long message for the user." 
        },
        "innererror": {
            "trace": [...],
            "context": {...}
        }
    }
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way of converting the response back into an ODataError.

Now I can write a custom JSON converter to do this, but it seems odd that this isn't available in the OData libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty standard library that can be added via NuGet called Newton Json Converter. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Example of Deserialization:

```
string json = @"{
"error": {
    "code": "A custom error code",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-us",
        "value": "A custom long message for the user." 
    },
    "innererror": {
        "trace": [...],
        "context": {...}
    }
  }
}";

var oDataError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataError>(json);
```

Comment: I am using NewtonSoft.Json, for some reason when I was testing this yesterday, it wasn't deserializing correctly - it now works, probably just tired :-)