# OData error response in .NET Core is not supported

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I need to send a response in case if error which is mentioned below:

[Example](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata03/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata03-os-complete.html#_Toc453766668)

```
"error": {
    "code": "501",
    "message": "Unsupported functionality",
    "target": "query",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "301",
            "target": "$search", 
            "message": "$search query option not supported"
        }
    ],
    "innererror": {
        "trace": [...],
        "context": {...}
    }
}
```

Any other way to achieve this Odata error response?

On researching I got ([Error Handling for ASP.NET Odata Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389070/error-handling-for-asp-net-odata-web-api))
but its 10 year old question and many things are not supporting now

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new ODataError { ErrorCode = "...", Message = "...", MessageLanguage = "..." }));
```

`CreateErrorResponse` is not found so I checked the namespaces I found `System.Net.Http` and `System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions` but its still not detecting.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct packages.  See : https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/odata-asp-net-core

Comment: @jdweng Yes this package is installed and other odata features are working.

Comment: So you followed all the instruction on link?  You should only use the packages on the link.  Then do a clean build.  Are you getting compiler errors?  What do you mean be "still not detecting"?

Comment: @jdweng Cleaned and Rebuild. Compiler error HttpRequest does not contains a defination for CreateErrorResponse

Comment: It is a static method (not instance) and is supported in Core 7.0 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.enablequeryattribute.createerrorresponse?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0.   Also see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=CreateErrorResponse&category=Documentation   Here is goo d example of how to use method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/httprequest-message-extension-method#createerrorresponse

Comment: @jdweng Solution Upgraded from 6.0 to 7.0 had to comment  due to ambigity

//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData; and use using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;

 ODataError error = new ODataError()
 {
     ErrorCode = "36",
     Message = "Bad stuff",
     InnerError = new ODataInnerError()
     {
         Message = "Exception message"
     }
 };
 return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
//Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataError' to 'string'

Comment: You should not be using Micosoft.AspNet (should be AspNetCore).  Should fix.  Check the csproj file with notepad and see if you can find AspNet.  The ambiguity can be fixed by using the full namespace for any wrong libraries.

Comment: @jdweng Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData  Microsoft.OData.Core AspNet.WebApi.OData Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core in my csproj

Comment: Not sure why you are getting an ambiguity error if you are just using Core.  Try a clean build.  Do you have any child projects that may not use Core?  Following may help https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/ or this https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2021/10/aspnet-core-swashbuckleaspnetcoreswagge.html

Comment: @jdweng I have done that. I will try to create a new project.